# How to use ML.Net to examine a models attributes and produce optimal model for targeted attribute

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, metrics, ml.net

I am looking for a method or technique using ML.Net to achieve the following:

Rather than predict I wish to target a desired attribute and find the optimal 'other attributes' to achieve this. For example:

Using the famous taxi fare example instead of predicting the next fare based on distance, passengers etc. I would like to say something like "for all fares that cost between $15 & $20 show me the best combination of attributes". **The actual usage, if it helps, is process engineering so for example here is the process**:

```
public class SampleDnaQcData
{
    [LoadColumn(0)]
    public float Volume { get; set; }
    [LoadColumn(1)]
    public float Viscosity { get; set; }
    [LoadColumn(2)]
    public float InstrumentTempreture { get; set; }
    [LoadColumn(3)]
    public float Concentration { get; set; }
    [LoadColumn(4)]
    public string SampleType { get; set; }
    [LoadColumn(5)]
    public float ResultAccuracy { get; set; } //this is the target attribute
}
```

I would like to be able to say.... find me the optimal conditions that created a ResultAccuracy closest to 100%.

I am looking for a method or technique using ML.Net that achieves this.

Hope this makes sense.

----EDIT----
I have built a clustering model that using ideas from this post https://rubikscode.net/2021/02/08/machine-learning-with-ml-net-complete-guide-to-clustering/

But I am unable to proceed because I simply do not know what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved with [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming).

[Here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-053-optimization-methods-in-management-science-spring-2013/tutorials/MIT15_053S13_tut01.pdf) you can find pretty simple introduction to this subject from MIT.

There are many solvers available -> [list of optimization software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_optimization_software). I can recommend GNU GLPK and lpsolve.

You can even define your model in MS Excel and use an addon from [solver.com](https://www.solver.com/) to check results in simple spreadsheet. After that you can easily move it to [RASON](https://rason.com/) and use theirs REST API.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for. A perfect starting point.